# Why is my FileReader not outputting codes from the .txt file?

Tags: java

Sorry If I have any errors because this is my first time asking a question. So basically, my program is converting white_space to underscore and I made it to work. But the problem is, I can't seem to output the inside of my outputfile.txt in the last part of my program.

There should be a premade inputfile.txt for it to work.

Full code:
https://pastebin.com/ecGGd1Z5

Here's the code I'm that's getting problem,

```
//READING2 No output :(
        FileReader yo = new FileReader ("outputfile.txt");
        int a;  
        System.out.println("Outputing from outputfile.txt file ...");
        while((a=yo.read())!=-1)
            {
                System.out.print((char)a);
            }
        System.out.println("\n");
        yo.close();
//
```

Comment: In your pastbin you open a filewriter and a fileread on the same file, but close the writer after you tried to read from the file. You can try to move `fwrite.close();` before you initialize `yo`. Also you should imo always close them as soon as possible or even better use try with resource.

Comment: @DerMaddi THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!!! This one solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not handling the resources correctly. Please find a working example bellow.

It uses "try with resource" so the resource e.g. a FileWriter will be closed correctly:

```
public class Working {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        String str;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("[Enter source file name: ]");
        String input = scan.nextLine();
        try (FileReader fread = new FileReader(input)) {
            BufferedReader bread = new BufferedReader(fread);
            try (FileWriter fwrite = new FileWriter("outputfile.txt")) {

                System.out.println("   ");
                System.out.println("Creating output file ...");
                System.out.println("Output file successly created!");
                System.out.println("[Output file name is outputfile.txt]");
                System.out.println("=====================");

                //READING
                FileReader fr = new FileReader(input);
                int i;
                System.out.println("Outputing from " + input + " file ...");
                while ((i = fr.read()) != -1) {
                    System.out.print((char) i);
                }
                System.out.println("\n");
                fr.close();
                //

                System.out.println("===========");
                System.out.println("Starting to convert spaces to underscore ...");
                System.out.println("Success!");
                System.out.println("===========");

                //
                while ((str = bread.readLine()) != null) {
                    str = str.trim();
                    str = str.replaceAll(" ", "_");
                    fwrite.write(str);
                }
            }
            //
            //READING2 No output :(
            try (FileReader yo = new FileReader("outputfile.txt")) {
                int a;
                System.out.println("Outputing from outputfile.txt file ...");
                while ((a = yo.read()) != -1) {
                    System.out.print((char) a);
                }
                System.out.println("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```